# CMake equivalent of APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I am moving an Android project from `ndk` to `CMake`.
In `Application.mk` we set following flag:

```
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS := true
```

But I couldn't find equivalent `cmake` flag for this. Can this be set from cmake arguments?

Comment: What do you need this for exactly? (i.e. why were you setting that flag in the first place)

Comment: Actually, there are many libraries in my app. I want cmake to not throw error if any lib in target_link_libraries() is missing. If lib is present then link else skip without throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this flag in ndk-build it means your Android.mk is wrong. That flag tells ndk-build to ignore garbage in your build script. It makes unknown dependencies exactly as meaningful as whitespace. The same behavior is achieved by removing the uses of the unknown deps from your Android.mk. ndk-build tells you this in the warning:

> Note that old versions of ndk-build silently ignored this error case. If your project worked on those versions, the missing libraries were not needed and you can remove those dependencies from the module to fix your build.
>
> Alternatively, set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies.